# Conditional Probability and Intersection probability

Tags: probability

I don't understand the formula of $P(A|B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$. I intuitively understand what conditional probability and intersection of two events occurring at the same time is. However, this formula is not very clear. I want to intuitively understand the relation. Any explanation or reference to some books or articles will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, it's understandable, but not correct, to associate *time* with conditional probability. $P(A|B)$ does not imply that $B$ came "first".

The formula for conditional probability is basically saying to calculate $P(A|B)$ we need to *restrict* our universe to the situation when $B$ has occurred.

$P(A \cap B)$ is simply the probability that $A$ and $B$ happen, which can be false if *either* $A$ or $B$ fails to happen. However, conditioning on $B$ happening takes $B^c$ out of the sample space. If we restrict our sample space to only events where $B$ happens, then $P(B|B)=1$, which is reflected in the formula: $\frac{P(B \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(B)}{P(B)}=1$ if $P(B)>0$

More generally $P(A|B)$ asks us how often $A$ occurs when $B$ has happened, so we need to look at the intersection of the two but normalize it so that $P(B|B)=1$.

Answer (score -1):

$P(A|B)$ is asking what the probability of $A$ is, given B has happened. The question then is "what fraction of the time that $B$ happens, does $A$ also happen? So we're dealing with the intersection of $A$ and $B$ with $B$ already having happened:[image]

The probability of $A$ while considering $B$ happened is going to be that dark shaded area as a fraction of the lighter shaded area $$\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$$
Think of an example, If I go to the movies with probability $0.6$ (think $A$) and go to a restaurant with probability $0.4$ (call it $B$) and both with probability $0.1$ (think $(A \cap B)$), what's the probability I go to a movie *given* I already went to a restaurant? Well, I go to a restaurant with probability $0.4$ and both a restaurant and a movie with probability $0.1$, so $\frac{0.1}{0.4}=0.25$ is the probability I go to a movie *given I went out to a restaurant already*.

It would make sense that the probability goes up to $0.25$ given I already did one of the $2$ things.

[here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter1/1_4_0_conditional_probability.php) is a decent source